# TypeScript Access Data from a Successfully Received Promise

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, promise

I am using the React Framework with TypeScript. 
My Problem is that I am trying to access Data from a successfully received promise using the fetch-method. So that i can already see (in the browser console) that there is an array with the needed data containend in the promise. That's my browser console output: [Chrome Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kztn.jpg)

The fetch is beeing executed as soon as the component mounts and saves the results in the state:

```
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.processJSON = this.processJSON.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        buecherJSON : []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/buecher/findAllByIsbnIsBefore?anzahl=2')
        .then(results => {
            this.setState({
                buecherJSON : results.json()
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

In separate method I want to process the JSON formatted data to make an object out of it. But I can't figure out how to make that. So i far i got this (which is basically doing nothing):

```
    processJSON(){

    var buecherJSON = this.state;
    console.log(Object.assign({},buecherJSON));
}
```

How can I map the received JSON to an accessible array in TypeScript?

Comment: And how do you plan to use `processJSON`, at what point?

Comment: At the moment it is beeing executed as a button onClick event:<button onClick={this.processJSON}>Verarbeite JSON</button>
Just to understand the basic processing.

Comment: Not clear what is your problem. So take `this.state.buecherJSON` and do with it whatever you want.

Comment: Basically i just want to know how to properly handle the received JSON data which is beeing stored in the state. As in:
this.state.buecherJSON.author